# Como apagar dados da base de dados?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, delete

Tenho este código para apagar os dados da base de dados em que o nome seja igual ao escolhido na combobox, cujo código 
e o segundo. Mas por algum motivo que não consigo descobrir qual não está a funcionar. Conseguem-me ajudar?

```
....
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
if (isset($_POST['botao_apagar']))
{
$cbnome= trim($_POST['cbMedicos']);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE * FROM Medicos WHERE nome= '".$cbnome."' "); 
$stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

código da combobox:

```
<label for="cbMedicos">Selecione um M&eacute;dico</label>
<select id="cbMedicos" name="cbMedicos">
<option>Selecione...</option>

<?php while($prod = $data->fetch_assoc()) { 
    echo '<option value="'.$prod['txtid'].'">'.$prod['txtNome'].'</option>';
    $meujson[$prod['txtid']] = $prod; // coleciona as linhas no $meujson


}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Na verdade ele está pegando o id do combobox e não o nome. Se for assim substitua `value="'.$prod['txtid']` por `value="'.$prod['txtNome']` ou na sua consulta você deleta por ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, Isabel!

No seu combobox está enviando o valor id e no delete você está tentando deletar por nome.

```
 echo '<option value="'.$prod['txtid'].'">'.$prod['txtNome'].'</option>';
```

Se você quer deletar por nome, então envie o nome no value

```
echo '<option value="'.$prod['txtNome'].'">'.$prod['txtNome'].'</option>';
```

Seu código até funciona, mas como ele não encontra nenhum nome que seja igual ao id que você está enviando, então ele não deleta nada.

Aí no seu php você coloca o comando DELETE:

```
DELETE FROM Medicos WHERE nome= '".$cbnome."' "
```

Creio que seja isso.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que sua query delete está incorreta. A sintaxe correta seria :

```
"DELETE FROM Medicos WHERE nome= ' ".$cbnome." ' "
```

sem o `*` (asterisco)

O `*` é utilizado para tags de consulta como um coringa para todos os campos da tabela. Na query delete está querendo deletar uma linha inteira de registro portanto não há sentido de utiliza-la ali.

Espeque que isso te ajude!

Comment: wildcard =  coringa ou seja todos o campos da tabela! =P

Comment: Entedi, valeu ;)

Comment: @RafaelSalomão mesmo assim continua sem funcionar

Comment: Faça o seguinte antes do seu código :

$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE * FROM Medicos WHERE nome= '".$cbnome."' ");   coloque isso : echo "DELETE * FROM Medicos WHERE nome= ' ".$cbnome." ' "  e post aqui a resposta!

Comment: Aproveita e verifica também se no seu formulário o botão para o post tem a propriedade name definida para "botao_apagar" se não estiver é provável que a rotina de delete não esteja sendo executada!